# Adding java variable to batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

Here's my updated code. This is the button being clicked in the class I made separate form the java class you provided. I know it says Ping (disregard that, I'm using the button for testing purposes) I don't see how they would reference each other with the Process P line of code you provided. What do you think?

```
JButton btnPingComputer = new JButton("PING");

        btnPingComputer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String line;
                BufferedWriter bw = null;
                BufferedWriter writer =null;
                try {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                String lineToRemove = "OU=Workstations";
                String s = null;

                Process p = null;
                try {
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\computerQuery.bat computerName");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {

                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\computerQuery.bat");

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer(); // new trial
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                        .getInputStream()));

                try {

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        System.out.println(line);

                        textArea.append(line);
                        textArea.append(String.format("  %s%n", line));
                        String dn = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
                        LdapName ldapName = new LdapName(dn);
                        String commonName = (String) ldapName.getRdn(ldapName.size() - 1).getValue();
                        System.out.println(commonName);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (InvalidNameException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally

                {
                    try {
                        fw.close();

                    }

                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {

                    in.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        });
```

Comment: You call the batch file with the parameter. How isn't this a duplicate of the last time you asked this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the parameter to your java program like this :

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\batFile.bat computerName");`

This will pass `parameter_to_pass` to the batch file.

**For your situation this code should work well:**

```
/*
This java program copies the value from a jTextField, adds it to a     predifined value 
and send it to command-line as a parameter. All these happens if you click     the jButton
*/


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class cmdJavaTest extends JFrame {
JTextField jTextField1 = new JTextField(20);
JButton jButton1 = new JButton("Click");
JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();

public cmdJavaTest() {
    super("CmdJavaParameterPass");

    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    getContentPane().add(jTextField1);
    getContentPane().add(jButton1);
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            sendParam();
        }
        });
        setSize(300, 170);
        setVisible(true);
    }

  public void sendParam(){
      try{
            String val = "Computer"+jTextField1.getText(); //Put whatever you want to pass as a prefix in place of "Computer"
            jLabel1.setText(val);
            Process p ;
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\batFile.bat "+val+"");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    new cmdJavaTest();
  }
}
```

**Use this as you test batch file content**
`@dsquery computer -name %1
pause`

But you must also see how to use a **[`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).**

Thanks, hope it helps

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80942/discussion-on-answer-by-mustangdc-adding-java-variable-to-batch-file).